# I have to create a form that would be for Maintenance?

Tags: email, form, forms-library

I have to create a form request,  then there would have to be an automated email and a 2nd email as well.  So basically there would be a web request form for the data, then the automatic email, then to track and report?

Anyone have an Idea on how to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Use workflows? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infopath can help with the form design if you are looking for customized forms and you can use the workflows for the automated emails. 
You can elaborate your question for more specific answers.
HTH

Comment: The problem is, I do not have access to workflow. which makes things a bit more difficult.  is there a way around that at all?

Comment: You might try the SPUtility.SendEmail if you have access to the object model.